# Prevent user from interacting with AVPlayerView?

Tags: cocoa, avplayer

I'm playing a video for decoration in my UI. I am hiding the AV player controls but it's still possible for the user to control the video. For instance, they can use swipe gestures to fast forward or rewind.

That's particularly surprising to me since the AVPlayerView has an overlay view on top of it.

Does anyone know how prevent all user interaction with this video?

Comment: Have you tried `playerView.userInteractionEnabled = false`?

Comment: I should clarify; I'm on OS X, not iOS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Swipe* gestures are generally three fingers, and from what I can tell these have no effect on the playback behavior of `AVPlayerView`; *scroll* gestures (two fingers) are the problem here. To do away with the default scroll-gesture implementation, you just need to override the `scrollWheel:` event handler on `AVPlayerView`:

```
import Cocoa
import AVKit

class PPPlayerView: AVPlayerView {

    var prohibitScrolling = true

    override func scrollWheel(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        if prohibitScrolling { 
             // just swallow the event 
        } else { 
            // request default behaviour
            super.scrollWheel(theEvent) 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also override `keyDown` to prevent the user from using the spacebar to pause the video.

Comment: I simply extended my `AVPlayerView`. I have only one view and no need for special custom features, so no need to subclass for me...

Comment: @AltairJones Could you please provide an example for your solution?

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: This does not seem to prevent trackpad two-finger swipe gestures from scrubbing the video player

Answer (score 1):

If your view is placed in a scroll view (or another view that needs to handle the mouse event), you may want to override hitTest: instead

```
- (NSView *)hitTest:(NSPoint)aPoint
{
   if (prohibitScrolling) {
      return nil;
   } else {
      return [super hitTest:aPoint];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do it with an extension in a new file, let's say in 'AVPlayerViewExtensions.swift' like this:

```
import Cocoa
import AVKit

extension AVPlayerView {

    override open func scrollWheel(with event: NSEvent) {
        // Disable scrolling that can cause accidental video playback control (seek)
        return
    }

    override open func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        // Disable space key (do not pause video playback)

        let spaceBarKeyCode = UInt16(49)
        if event.keyCode == spaceBarKeyCode {
            return
        }
    }

}
```